# Number of operations in standard Swift math functions

Tags: swift, math, concurrency

I'm trying to make the efficiency of a parallel algorithm and looking for number of operations of standard math functions in Swift (exp, sin, cos, pow, abs). Does anybody knows where can I find it? Or maybe realization of this functions?

Answer (score 1):

Swift gets its math functions from `Darwin` which gets the functions from `math.h`

You can find all available functions here: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/math.3.html

You also have the `Accelerate` framework which is used mostly for vectors and matrices.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate

Comment: Thank’s, but there is only description. Can’t find their number of operation or algorithms, which Apple use for this funcs.